# How to change the font size of all tables in a word document using a vba macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with a lot of tables. I would like a macro which changes the fonts size of all tables to 10, autofits each table to the window and distributes the columns evenly. I can accomplish the last two goals using the below code, but not sure how to change the font size. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub changetables()
Dim tbl As Table
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    tbl.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
    tbl.Columns.DistributeWidth

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your exact code use

```
   tbl.Range.Font.Size = 12
```

I have retyped a few things to show better naming and spacing etc.

```
 Sub changetables()

      Dim CurrentTable As Table

      For Each CurrentTable In ActiveDocument.Tables

           With CurrentTable

                .AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
                .Columns.DistributeWidth
                .Range.Font.Size = 12
           End With

      Next CurrentTable

 End Sub
```

Comment: How to change fonts to calibri?
for font size I used tbl.Range.Font.Size = 12 and it worked.
What properties should I use for font family.

Answer (score 0):

Just change .size to .name, as in tbl.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"

This should also work for whatever font name you wish to use by replacing Calibri within the double quotes to your desired font name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).